# How to get in php foreach value from other array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I get images in a array then i read it with a *foreach* this are images, but how can i get also image text, my example is here:

```
    $slideImages = array('image/path/image1', 'image/path/image2', 'image/path/image13');
    $slideText = array('image text 1', 'image text 2', 'image text 3');

    if($slideImages) :
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($slideImages as $slideImage) :
?>
            <li>
                <div>IMAGE TEXT</div>
                <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" />
            </li>
<?php
        endforeach;

        echo '</ul>';

    endif;
```

I need to embed also image text from the true position, i know how to do it with *for* but so is not efficient... it's something like this possible?

Comment: use the key from the first array to match the 2nd

Comment: Use [SPL MultipleIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change the way you store the info and keep them in one multidimensional array.

```
$slides = array( 
    array( image => "image/path/image1", text => "image text 1"),
    array( image => "image/path/image2", text => "image text 2"),
    array( image => "image/path/image3", text => "image text 3")
);
```

Then you would iterate through the $slides array and just pull out the image and text for each:

```
foreach($slides as $slide)
{
            echo "Text:".$slide["text"];
            echo "Image Path:".$slide["image"];
}
```

This organizes your code a little better so you don't wind up with something crazy going on should your two arrays wind up out of sync.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the keys are the same, use the `$key` in the foreach:

```
foreach($slideImages as $key => $slideImage) :
?>
            <li>
                <div>IMAGE TEXT</div>
                <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" />
                <?php echo $slideText[$key]; ?>
            </li>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: no need to assume, the code says the keys are the same

Comment: Yes, it also says `image/path/image1` and `image text 1` so I assumed it was example code.

Answer (score 0):

simplified example:

```
 foreach($slideImages as $key=>$var){

echo $var;
echo $slideText[$key];
}
```